# how to get several same object values in a Grails form

Tags: forms, grails, grails-plugin

let's take a simpe domain class:

```
class Person { String aname }
```

A gsp form to let the user input a person is easy:

```
<g:form ...>
...
  someone:<input name="aname">
...
</g:form>
```

... and back in the controller, to get the values, I can just write

```
def p = new Person(params)
```

Now, I'd like to let the user input the data for two persons (let's say, two parents) in the same form. How to write this ? I just can't give the same name for the two input fields, but if I don't keep the original property name ("aname"), back in the controller I will have to handle by hand the bindings between the name of the property, and the form input names:

```
<g:form ...>
...
  father:<input name="aname1">
  mother:<input name="aname2">
...
</g:form>
```

then, in controller

```
def p1 = new Person(); p1.aname = params.aname1
def p2 = new Person(); p2.aname = params.aname2
```

Is there a way to keep the automatic binding facility even if there is several objects of same types given in a form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this way:

```
<g:form ...>
...
  father:<input name="father.aname">
  mother:<input name="mother.aname">
...
</g:form>
```

And controller:

```
def p1 = new Person(params.father); 
def p2 = new Person(params.mother);
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Cat, this dot notation is what I was looking for ... at least for the basic <input> tag.

Sadly, it does not work within fields plugin: I can write <f:field bean="mother" property="name">, but in that case, the returned param will by "name", and not "mother.name".

And there is no way to write <f:field property="mother.name">. 

Let's stay with <input> tag, then.

Comment: have you tried to set <f:field bean="mother" property="name" name="mother.name">?

Comment: no, adding a "name" attribute does nothing more, but i discovered another "prefix" one that does the jobb. I explain this below, as an anwser (rather than an unformatted comment).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are thinking of doing something like this:

```
<g:form ...>
...
  father:<input name="aname">
  mother:<input name="aname">
...
</g:form>
```

which would result as `?aname=Dad&aname=Mom`

You can handle them in controller as below:

```
params.list('aname').each{eachName -> //Persist each `aname`}
```

Have a look at [`Handling Multi Parameters`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects).

Answer (score 0):

the dot notation in the "name" attribute works well for the `<input>` tag.

To go further, there is also a solution for the "fields" plugin: rather than using the "name" attribute, one should use the "prefix" one, as [described here](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html).

For example:

```
<f:field bean="mother" property="forename" prefix="mother."/>
<f:field bean="mother" property="surname"  prefix="mother."/>
<f:field bean="father" property="forename" prefix="father."/>
<f:field bean="father" property="surname"  prefix="father."/>
```

we can even write it better, with help of `<f:with>` tag:

```
<f:with bean="mother"  prefix="mother.">
   <f:field property="forename"/>
   <f:field property="surname"/>
</f:with>
<f:with bean="father"  prefix="father.">
   <f:field property="forename"/>
   <f:field property="surname"/>
</f:with>
```